# fit a general img into responsive div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having trouble fitting a general `img` inside a responsive `div`.

My restrictions are:

1. Maintain the aspect ratio of the `img`
2. The `img` must cover all `div`, i.e. both `height` and `width` must be greater than `100%`
3. The size of the`img` must be as minimum as possible, i.e. `height=100%` or `width=100%`
4. The `img` should be centered in relation to the `div`

In other words I want to fit an image inside a container in such a way that I won't distort it and I will totally cover the container, while showing most of the image and keeping it centered.

If it simplifies I know that my `img` is always bigger than my `div`

All solutions encountered only satisfied a subset of the conditions

Comment: If you can use background images the css3 propety background-size:cover; is very useful

Comment: I think you want to set the image as a background image, and then set the background-size to 'cover'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the background to your image and add the following to your css:

```
background-image: url("YOUR_IMAGE_PATH_HERE");
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
```

See **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ofxqjg07/1/)**

Comment: This workaround does the trick that I needed. Unfortunately it uses background images.

Comment: You're going to need to use background images in order to get what you want.

Comment: Yea unfortunately I don't know any other way of doing it without calculating the dimensions using js or some hack like that =/

Answer (score 0):

The only decent way of doing this easily, is by setting the image a background image of the container div. Simply place the image as a background image and set the background size to be cover.

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

And your CSS:

```
#myDiv {
    width:320px;
    height:240px;
    background:url('your-url.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
}
```

In this example, you can stipulate whatever width and height you want for the container, and the image will cover the entire size, whilst maintaining the image aspect ratio.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/e1ma5gpr/

This might be useful to read! - http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/

Comment: @NunoCalaim Have fixed it now, this entire code should satisfy all your requirements. :)